# Which thread does Runnable run on?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I want to update UI every 100ms. After searching in StackOverflow, I found a solution using `Runnable` and `Handler` like this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //update UI here

        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

It works! But I have some questions:

1. Which thread does this `Runnable` run on? MainThread or another thread? Here is the docs about `postDelay`
   [image]

`Handler` is attached MainThread, so is `Runnable` running on MainThread?

2. If `Runnable` is running on MainThread, why needs `Handler`? According to my knowledge, `Handler` is used to send messages between two threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Which thread does this Runnable run on?

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //update UI here

        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
runnable.run()
```

This `Runnable` runs on the current thread, i.e. the thread that invokes this code. It doesn't magically create, or constitute, another thread. `Runnable.run()` is only a method call.

The *subsequent* executions of this thread, by the `Handler`, in whatever thread the `Handler` runs in, do essentially nothing except reschedule themselves. It's hard to believe this is a solution to anything.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `Runnable` runs on the UI Thread.

If you want your `Handler` and all its `Runnable` to run in a different Thread, you'll have to assign it a a new [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html)'s `Looper`.

```
final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(MY_THREAD_ID);
handlerThread.start();
final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
```

You can then pass the `Runnable` instance via `postDelayed(Runnable, long)`.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }   
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 0);
```

Comment: Not the first time.

Comment: @EJP you mean not to call `postDelayed` the first time?

Comment: `runnable.run()` is first invoked by the current thread. Next time and thereafter it is invoked by the `Handler`. Not the first time.

Comment: @pskink The statement 'in your example, the `Runnable` runs on the UI Thread' and my comment both refer to the OP's code, which is what the question is actually about.

Comment: @EJP the first `Runnable` execution is invoked by the `Handler`. From the beginning, you are running on a separate thread, ...

Comment: @payloc The final line of the OP's code is `runnable.run()`, and it is invoked by the current thread, and it has exactly nothing to do with the `Handler` whatsoever.

Comment: @pskink I can only suggest you re-read the question. It's up there in black and white. I copy/pasted if from there into my own answer.

Comment: @pskink It is indeed, when you keep making counterfactual claims in defiance of the evidence of your own eyes. `runnable.run();` is up there in black and white in the OP's question, from where I have just copy/pasted it *again*.

Comment: @pskink Evidently you can't indeed. `runnable.run()` (a) is present in the OP's code and (b) runs in the current thread. No two ways about it.