# Problems in running handlers?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, debugging, handler

I am trying to call my takepicture() method after every 1 minute. So, I tried using the handler class and then tried calling my method within its run function. However, when I tried doing a step wise debugging, it never enters the run method at all. Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to call it from my fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("HandlerThread","This is from the HandlerThread");
            takePicture();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
            }
        };


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic.jpg");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("HandlerThread","This is from the HandlerThread");
        takePicture();
        }
    }, 60000);
}
```

Rather than defining the handler.postDelayed within run method.I have just changed the call within your main thread itself.

Kindly mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You never call any method that would run the `Runnable`. You only specified its behavior inside the `run()` function.

In order to start the `Runnable`, call something like `handler.postDelayed(r, 0);`

---

Just an info: please note that your `Handler` is still tied to the main `Thread`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670169/which-thread-does-runnable-run-on/47670397#47670397) answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856376/android-why-cant-i-create-a-handler-in-new-thread) if you want to run it on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an initial call to start the handler functionality.
ie , `handler.post(r);`